# Cannot find module in JS but can find it in CS

Tags: javascript, coffeescript

**ANSWER** because CS and JS use their own respective language modules. i had to port the entire hubot code from CS to JS.

I have 1 file named test with the following contents

```
global.hubot = require('hubot')
```

`coffee test` runs the file with no complaints.
 `global.hubot` is defined and declared to the contents of `../../node_modules/hubot`

**The problem** is `node test` exits with

> ERROR: module 'hubot' cannot be found.

For some reason I figured that if it worked in coffeescript it had to work in javascript, what are the differences here? it seems like all the other modules i have installed load fine in both languages.

Answer (score 0):

You can also use `coffee-script/register` in your JS:

```
require('coffee-script/register')
x = require('whatever.coffee')
```